# Como inserir um if/else dentro de um echo?

Tags: php

```
echo '<option value="0" {if/else} >Em revisão</option>';
echo '<option value="1" {if/else} >Publicado</option>';
```

Gostaria de ter uma condição `if/else` para perguntar ao banco de dados o valor e dar um `selected` no valor retornado. Podem me ajudar?

Seria alguma coisa tipo: `if($resultado['status'] == 1) { echo 'selected=selected'; }`

Comment: consegue passar mais detalhes?

Comment: Acredito que sua lógica esteja certo. Só o selected=selected que deve ser, na string final, assim: selected="selected". Só adicionar as aspas. Ou se for html5, somente `selected` resolve

Comment: O problema é que eu insiro o {if/else} dentro do echo e dá erro. Estou tendo problemas para passar a instrução certa dentro do echo.

Comment: Olhe esse exemplo:
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.if($value=='United States') echo 'selected="selected"';.'>'.$value.'</option>';

Comment: Você pode fazer o seguinte: 
echo '<option value="0" ' . ($resultado['status'] == 1) ? 'selected=selected' : '' . ' >Em revisão</option>';
echo '<option value="1" ' . ($resultado['status'] == 1) ? 'selected=selected' : '' . ' >Publicado</option>';

Comment: Credo parece uma coisa tão simples ... se eu colocar html puro consigo fazer abrindo as tags **PHP** mas dentro do echo não consigo.

Comment: Isso ai está dentro de um foreach?

Comment: Você não está sendo claro. Falta informação ai.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar da seguinte forma:

```
echo '<option value="0" ' . (($resultado['status'] == 0) ? 'selected=selected' : '') . ' >Em revisão</option>';
echo '<option value="1" ' . (($resultado['status'] == 1) ? 'selected=selected' : '') . ' >Publicado</option>';
```

Comment: Perfeito. Eu já tinha tentado fazer algo igual mas parece que a instrução **selected=selected** estava bugando o código. Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi porque essa resposta recebeu -1. Vocês não curtem concatenação?

Comment: Sugestão de melhoria: passe o espaço em branco da string para dentro o ternário, assim não fica espaço sobrando na tag caso não tenha `select`. E na primeira linha, seria ` == 0` não?

Answer (score 8):

Utilize [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) e [`ternario`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

#### Código

```
$dadoBanco = 1;

$option = '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>';

$selected = 'selected="selected"';

echo sprintf($option, 0, ($dadoBanco == 0) ? $selected : '', 'Em revisão');
echo sprintf($option, 1, ($dadoBanco == 1) ? $selected : '', 'Publicado');
```

Comment: Essa seria a minha resposta xD. +1 só trocaria o sprintf, por printf :P

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar if ternário, assim:

```
<?php
$selected = $resultado['status'] == 1 ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
echo '<option value="1" ' . $selected . '>Publicado</option>';
echo '<option value="0" ' . $selected . '>Em revisão</option>';
```

Answer (score 4):

Para o caso atributo selected eu faria uma expressão com a função `printf`.

Assim:

```
  printf('<select %s></select>', $resultado['status'] == 1 ? 'selected' : '');
```

Se isso fosse no próprio `HTML` eu utilizaria a função `print` do PHP, combinada com uma expressão

Assim:

```
<select <?php $resultado['status'] == 1 && print 'selected' ?>></select>
```

Observação: Não dá pra fazer a mesma coisa com o `echo`

Comment: haaa `printf` \o.

Comment: A expressão com `print` também é bacana. Alcança coisas que `echo` não faz :)

Comment: vc consegue o mesmo resultado com echo, precisa mudar a sintaxe um pouco, igual está na resposta escolhida.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito dessa forma.

```
<?php
$value='United States';
$selected = ($value)=='United States'?'selected':'';
echo "<select>";
echo "<option>Teste</option>";
echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$value.'</option>';
echo "</select>";
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Acho que isso pode lhe ajudar

```
<?php

$valor_select = $_POST['select'];

$valor_compara = '1';

echo '<select name="select" id="select">';
foreach($array_select as $val){
    $sel = ($val == valor_select)?'selected="selected"':'';

    echo '<option value="'.$val.'" '.$sel.'>'.$val.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```